# Updating marker every 5/10 seconds with mapbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm currently working with MapBox and OpenSky APIs to retrieve airplanes currently in the skies. Everything is working correctly but I'm just struggling to update the planes locations. Once map is loaded it will ask for location to display the flights at user current location. From my point of view plane markers are deploy statically and they will not update. Is there any way how to update it ??? Here is my actual code below.

```js
// user info to determine the center
let lat;
let lon;

// map api fetch
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY29kZXByb2RpZ3kiLCJhIjoiY2tlNWxtNHJjMTRkbjJ6bzRjajlhYmx4MSJ9.HklunmwPVXRpFLP0r-zekg';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [0,0]
});

// flights api fetch data
const flight_api = 'https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all';
fetch(flight_api)
.then(response => {
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
    let data_array = data.states;
    data_array.forEach((el,index) => {
        var geojson = {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'features': [
                {
                    'type': 'Feature',
                    'properties': {
                    'iconSize': [40, 40]
                    },
                    'geometry': {
                    'type': 'Point',
                    'coordinates': [el[5],el[6]]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        //custom marker
        window.setInterval(() => {
            geojson.features.forEach(marker =>{
            // create a DOM element for the marker
            var plane_marker = document.createElement('div');
            plane_marker.className = 'marker';

            new mapboxgl.Marker(plane_marker)
            .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
            .addTo(map);
            })
            console.log('updated');
        }, 10000);
    })

    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lon = position.coords.longitude;
            map.setCenter([lon, lat]);
            map.setZoom(8)
        })
    }

    var nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl();
    map.addControl(nav, 'top-left');

    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.FullscreenControl({container: document.querySelector('body')}));
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.marker {
    background-image: url('../assets/airplane.png');
    background-size: cover;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.map_div {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}

#map { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- <meta name="theme-color" content="#3367D6"/> -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/rsz_airplane.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="assets/rsz_airplane.png">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Easy Flight Tracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <!-- <link rel='manifest' href='manifest.json'> -->
</head>
<body>

<div class="map_div">
    <div id='map'></div>
</div>

<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bf71c6be93.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src='scripts/app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to request new data each time.

Comment: can you provide some further info about this ? Should I put the the request into interval ?

Comment: Yes...exactly. Note you should check the api query limits if they have any. Seems like when zoom is large scale you won;t see much variation in just a  few seconds